# Why need list argument in list splice func cpp

Tags: c++, list, linked-list, undefined-behavior, splice

Why do we need a list argument in the splice func cpp? Why only iterators aren't sufficient?
Result is the same if I pass `l1` or `l2` as a second argument
`l1.splice(st, l1, it, it2);` or `l1.splice(st, l2, it, it2);`

prints `1 4 5 2 3`

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h> 
using namespace std; 

int main() 
{ 


// initializing lists and iterator 
list<int> l1 = { 1, 2, 3 }; 
list<int> l2 = { 4, 5 }; 

auto it = l2.begin(); 
auto it2 = l2.end(); 

auto st = l1.begin();
std::advance(st,1);

// result the same if in splice l1 or l2
// 1 4 5 2 3 
l1.splice(st, l2, it, it2); 

cout << "list l1 after splice operation" << endl; 
for (auto x : l1) 
    cout << x << " "; 
return 0; 
}
```

Comment: If you pass `l1` as the list argument, then you have undefined behaviour (which can included *seeming* to work). See [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list/splice): *The behavior is undefined if other refers to the same object as *this.*

Comment: For others reading this, in a release build, an iterator is just a raw pointer to a node in a list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This call

```
l1.splice(st, l1, it, it2);
```

invokes undefined behavior.

When you need to extract a range of elements then other data members of the list as for example `size` must be updated.

If you will execute for example this statement

```
std::cout << l2.size() << '\n';
```

you can get unexpected result.

Here is a demonstrative program compiled with gcc 8.3.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <list>
#include <iterator>

int main() 
{
    std::list<int> lst1 = { 1, 3, 5, 7, 9 };
    std::list<int> lst2 = { 0, 2, 4, 6, 8 };

    lst1.splice( std::next( std::begin( lst1 ) ), 
                            lst1, 
                            std::begin( lst2 ),
                            std::end( lst2 ) );

    for ( const auto &item : lst1 )
    {
        std::cout << item << ' ';
    }
    std::cout << '\n';

    for ( const auto &item : lst2 )
    {
        std::cout << item << ' ';
    }
    std::cout << '\n';

    std::cout << "the size of lst2 is " << lst2.size() << '\n';

    return 0;
}
```

Its output is

```
1 0 2 4 6 8 3 5 7 9 

the size of lst2 is 5
```

If you will change `lst1` to `lst2` in this call

```
    lst1.splice( std::next( std::begin( lst1 ) ), 
                            lst2,                 // <=== 
                            std::begin( lst2 ),
                            std::end( lst2 ) );
```

then you will the correct output

```
1 0 2 4 6 8 3 5 7 9 

the size of lst2 is 0 
                   ^^^
```

Comment: For others reading this, in a release build, an iterator is just a raw pointer to a node in a list.

Answer (score 1):

What @Adrian Mole said in comment is *partially* right: `l1.splice(st, l1, it, it2);` **will** cause undefined behaviour, but it's not for this reason:

> The behavior is undefined if other refers to the same object as *this.

As [exactly the cppreference page he referred to](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list/splice) says:

- for overload `void splice(const_iterator pos, list& other);` (and rvalue list variant), the behavior is undefined if *this and other refer to the same object.
- for overload `void splice(const_iterator pos, list& other, const_iterator first, const_iterator last);` (and rvalue list variant), the behavior is undefined if [first, last) is not a valid range in other, or pos is in [first, last).

The real cause of undefined behavior is:

> [first, last) is not a valid range in other

So at least at the document point of view, it's okay to splice from *this as long as position of insertion is not contained in the specified range.

However, the question is not answered: we just gave the C++ documentation
and said: This is undefined behavior, Don't do so! Yet we still don't know:

> Why only iterators aren't sufficient?

I think a potential reason is that allocator of *this and other should be the same, so other should be passed for checking.